# How to get sessionid from spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services

I am building rest webservices in Java,so that it could be consumed by other clients.By following this link http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html I have build basic curd operations with spring Hibernate.

Now I am trying to implement session management in webservice,even though i have searched about this in google i have not got idea to implement session in below code.

RestController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class RestController {

@Autowired
DataServices dataServices;

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RestController.class);

/* Submit form in Spring Restful Services */
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Status addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    try {
        dataServices.addEntity(employee);
                    return new Status(1, "Employee added Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return new Status(0, e.toString());
    }

}

/* Ger a single objct in Json form in Spring Rest Services */
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    Employee employee = null;
    try {
        employee = dataServices.getEntityById(id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employee;
}

/* Getting List of objects in Json format in Spring Restful Services */
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List getEmployee() {

    List employeeList = null;
    try {
        employeeList = dataServices.getEntityList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return employeeList;
}

/* Delete an object from DB in Spring Restful Services */
@RequestMapping(value = "delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Status deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    try {
        dataServices.deleteEntity(id);
        return new Status(1, "Employee deleted Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Status(0, e.toString());
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Status saveUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Employee employee) {
    Employee employeeupdate = null;

    try {
        employeeupdate = dataServices.getEntityById(id);
        employeeupdate.setId(employee.getId());
        employeeupdate.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
        employeeupdate.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
        employeeupdate.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
        employeeupdate.setPhone(employee.getPhone());
        dataServices.updateEntity(employeeupdate);

        return new Status(1, "Employee updated Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return new Status(0, e.toString());
    }
}}
```

DataDaoImpl.java

```
 public class DataDaoImpl implements DataDao {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;

@Override
public boolean addEntity(Employee employee) throws Exception {

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(employee);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return false;
}

@Override
public Employee getEntityById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Employee employee = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, new Long(id));
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return employee;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List getEntityList() throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List employeeList = session.createCriteria(Employee.class).list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return employeeList;
}

@Override
public boolean deleteEntity(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Object o = session.load(Employee.class, id);
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(o);
    tx.commit();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean updateEntity(Employee employeeupdate) throws Exception {

    // session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(employeeupdate);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return false;
}}
```

Here my questions are:

1. how could I maintain session by checking if valid user
2. how could I send session id to other client(client application is developed in other platform). So it keep track of session.
3. how to make request and response to happen in same valid session.
4. should all this be done in server webservice side?

Any suggestion and help is appreciated.

Comment: How You are validating the user ?

Comment: @anand mishra i am just doing sample on web services.as if now i have planned to validate user by comparing data in database.If i can use spring authentication i want to check on that,if u have any suggestion or links it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Use java UUID to generate session key at the time of authentication and store it in Google Guava cache and validate it with every subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

Use java UUID to generate key at the time of authentication and You can use Google Guava cache or database for storing key and validate it with every subsequent request.
The steps will be as-.

1- Client logs in with username+password.

2- Server validates and returns a uuid/token and store  token along with userId in cache.

3- Client makes a request.

4- Server looks at token in request.

5- Server looks up the token and determines if the token is expired or not present.

6- If the token is expired or not present the server returns an error.

7- If the token is not expired the server returns the data in a response.